# graded cocommutative and coassociative coalgebra, cofree in the category of locally nilpotent differential graded coalgebras

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebroids

For someone who is new to Lie $\infty$-algebras, the title looks confusing. This is how Lie $\infty$-algebras are commonly described, for example, see [What is a homotopy between $L_\infty$-algebra morphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139175/what-is-a-homotopy-between-l-infty-algebra-morphisms)

Many people think of Lie algebroids as NQ-manifolds with the excuse that it is easy to write down the notion of morphisms between two Lie algebroids over different manifolds. To support this argument, there are very less number of papers, notes that give an explicit description of Lie algebroid morphism over different base manifolds. I know only one place that is Definition 2.17 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611259

The question of thinking Lie $\infty$-algebroids is too far from being comfortable. I don't know a single place where there is an explicit description of morphisms of Lie $\infty$-algebroids without referring to NQ-manifolds.

Question: Are there any real benifits to thinking of Lie $\infty$-algebras(oids) in that way?